# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

new to three.js I am following the documentation and when I come to this point:

```
                 function animate(renderer, scene, camera, cube) {
                    requestAnimationFrame( animate);
                    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
                    renderer.render( scene, camera );
                 }

                 function init() {
                   var scene = new THREE.Scene(); //setup scene
                   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / 
                   window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);//setup camera; 75= fov is the extent of the scene 
                   that is seen on the display at any given moment; il rapporto è l'asect ratio;

                   var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();//setup renderer;renderer istance;
                   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                   var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1 , 1); //thisobject that contains all 
                   the points;
                   var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0x00ff00 }); // to color it;
                   var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material); // object that takes a geometry 
                   and applies a material it;
                   console.log(cube);
                   scene.add(cube);
                   camera.position.z = 5; // move the camera a little bit from the cube,

                   animate(renderer, scene, camera, cube);
                 }
                   window.onload = init;
```

I'm trying to load an object and then perform a rotation on it, but get an error reported. The object loads fine but reports many of the same error. I've researched the problem and understand that it might be to do with asynchronous loading of objects, but I just can't figure out how this applies to mine

Answer (score 0):

> I've researched the problem and understand that it might be to do with asynchronous loading of objects

Your issue is unrelated to asynchronous loading since your are not loading assets from a backend.

The actual problem is that you declare `cube` inside of your `init()` function. Hence, the variable is not visible in `animate()`. The solution is to declare `cube` outside of both functions.

Comment: thanks I declare cube and the other variables outside the init function  but then I get THREE is not defined even if I add the Three.js CDN in my HTML file

Comment: Can you demonstrate your issue with a live example? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Answer (score 0):

To clarify @Mugen87 's answer, you don't need to move your entire definition outside, just the variable declaration.

```js
var cube = null

function animate(){
  // ...
}

function init(){
  // ...
  cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  // ...
}
```

JavaScript is functionally-scoped, meaning its variables are scoped to the function in which they are defined (which includes any functions defined in the same scope).